# Creating arrays in Python without pre-populating with data

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

`enter code here`Is there a way to create (multidimensional) arrays in Python, without pre-populating these arrays with data?

Specifically I'm looking for something equivalent to the Ironpython solution I found [here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Typed_Arrays_in_IronPython) :

```
import clr

from System import Array,Boolean,Double

from System.Activator import CreateInstance

a=clr.Reference[Array[str]](Array[str](('')))

b=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
```

I tryed with ctypes (e.g.  a=(c_double*2*3)()  ) but this way arrays are prepopulated with zeros.
Any idea?

The problem is that I have a COM object with an API which functions are something like:

ret=function(var1,var2,var3,...)

where var1,var2,var3 are multidimensional arrays to be filled by values.
If I use Ironpython I can communicate with the COM object via the System module like:

```
from System.Type import GetTypeFromProgID
from System.Activator import CreateInstance

# Create Sap2000 object
sap = CreateInstance(GetTypeFromProgID("Sap2000.SapObject"))
```

and then I solve my problem by building var1, var2, var3 with clr.Reference...

With CPython I used the win32com.client module to communicate with the COM object but now I don't know how to build the var1, var2, var3 so that they work in the function.

Thanks,

HERE'S THE CODE:

```
import win32com.client 
from ctypes import*


def Sap2000():
    sap,SapModel=OpenSap2000(Visible = True)
    NewModel(SapModel)

    #define material property
    ret = SapModel.PropMaterial.SetMaterial("CONC", 2) #MATERIAL_CONCRETE)

    #assign isotropic mechanical properties to material
    ret = SapModel.PropMaterial.SetMPIsotropic("CONC", 3600, 0.2, 0.0000055)

    #create model from template
    ret = SapModel.File.New2DFrame(0, 3, 124, 3, 200) # 0=PortalFrame

    #run analysis
    ret = SapModel.File.Save("C:\SapAPI\xy.sdb")
    ret = SapModel.Analyze.RunAnalysis

    #clear all case and combo output selections
    ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.DeselectAllCasesAndCombosForOutput

    #set case and combo output selections
    ret = SapModel.Results.Setup.SetCaseSelectedForOutput("DEAD")

    #get point displacements

    # Arrays passed by ref
    #Obj=clr.Reference[Array[str]](Array[str](('')))
    Obj=[[""]]
    #Elm=clr.Reference[Array[str]](Array[str](('')))
    Elm=[[""]]
    #LoadCase=clr.Reference[Array[str]](Array[str](('')))
    LoadCase=[[""]]
    #StepType=clr.Reference[Array[str]](Array[str](('')))
    StepType=[[""]]

    #StepNum=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    StepNum=(c_double*3*2)()
    #U1=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    U1=(c_double*3*2)()
    #U2=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    U2=(c_double*3*2)()
    #U3=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    U3=(c_double*3*2)()
    #R1=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    R1=(c_double*3*2)()
    #R2=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    R2=(c_double*3*2)()
    #R3=clr.Reference[Array[float]](Array.CreateInstance(Double,0))
    R3=(c_double*3*2)()
    ret = SapModel.Results.JointDispl("ALL", GroupElm, NumberResults, Obj, Elm, LoadCase, StepType, StepNum, U1, U2, U3, R1, R2, R3)
    print ret




def OpenSap2000(Units='kN_m_C',Visible = False,FileName=''):
    # Create Sap2000 object
    sap = win32com.client.Dispatch("Sap2000.SapObject")

    # Start application
    ret=sap.ApplicationStart(6,Visible,FileName)
    print ret
    SapModel=sap.SapModel

    return sap,SapModel


def NewModel(SapModel,Units='kN_m_C'):
    # Initialize new model
    #SapModel=sap.SapModel
    u=SetUnits(Units)
    ret = SapModel.InitializeNewModel(u)
    # New blank model
    ret = SapModel.File.NewBlank()
    return


if __name__=="__main__":
    Sap2000()
```

It fails calling the SapModel.Results.JointDispl(..) function.

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 456, in *ApplyTypes*
    self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.

Comment: Why is it necessary for there to be no data there? Is it because you think it's faster that way?

Comment: I added some specs to the first post about the problem I'm trying to face. @Cosmologicon: the performance is not the problem @lazyr: I'm looking at your link

Comment: Why don't you show us the code using win32com.client up to the point it doesn't work.  For all the guessing below no one understands your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `list` entries have so have some value in but you could use [`None`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#None).

For a one dimension "array" it's as simple as:

```
[None] * 3
```

For a two-dimensional array you have to more careful, as you don't want all your nested lists to the same list, so you can do something like:

```
[[None] * 2 for _ in range(3)]
```

Another option is to use a `dict` with tuples as keys but this doesn't have a fixed size either.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[(1,1)] = 2
>>> d[(1,1)]
2
>>> d[(1,2)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: (1, 2)
```

The [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) offers typed numeric arrays but these are like a `list` in that they don't have a fixed size.  However, these do need to be populated with a value.

```
>>> from array import array
>>> a = [array('f',[0] * 2) for _ in range(3)]
>>> a
[array('f', [0.0, 0.0]), array('f', [0.0, 0.0]), array('f', [0.0, 0.0])]
>>> a[1][1] = 3.4
>>> a[1][1] = 'string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using NumPy, you can use [`numpy.empty()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html).  NumPy is probably the best available implementation of a multidimensional array.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem cause numpy.empty(n) returns a numpy array like --> array([  1.25350215e-163,   9.98394023e-317,   1.58456325e+029], ...)

Comment: @Paolo, an array has to contain **something**.  So **unpopulated** doesn't really have any meaning.  Do you mean **uninitialized**?  An array is created faster if it doesn't have to be filled with a known value, and `numpy.empty()` is an uninitialized array.

Comment: Please look at the Ironpython topic I linked at the beginning. I just used the same words I found there.

Answer (score 1):

What should it be pre-populated with? What is your use case?

I think the quickest solution for an array of dimensions (x, y) would be:

```
a = [[None] * x for i in range(y)]
```

This will give you a multidimensional array with `None` values denoting where you haven't set any value yet.

Comment: Inside `a` you've got the same list three times so, for example, when you change `a[1][1]` you'll change `a[0][1]` and `a[0][2]` at the same time.

Comment: I should assign a type but not the dimension nor the values. Let's say I want a multidimensional array (2 layers) of doubles or strings (as in the Ironpython example I posted).

Comment: You're both wrong: Daren: it need to end with "for i in range(y)", and Dave, this is the right way to avoid the shared list problem.

Comment: @Ned - Daren has edited his answer since I added my comment.  It originally said `[[None] * x] * y`.

Comment: Assigning None values doeasn't solve my problem. It's like I need to declare a variable in python...maybe using Cython??

Comment: I added some specs to the first post